# how do i calculate the equilibrium of price and quantity in this given demand function?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, economics

how do i calculate it?

```
Qd = 900 - 10p

p = 15 + 0.05Qs
```

**This is what have tried.**

```
making Qs the subject of formular

p - 15 = 0.05Qs

Qs= (p-15)/0.05

then now to solve the equlibrium

Qd=Qs

900 - 10p = (p-15)/0.05

(900 - 10p)* 0.05 = p - 15

45 - 0.5p = p - 15

45 + 15 = p + 0.05p

60 = 1.05p

p = 60/1.05 = 57.1

insert p into Qd

Qd = 900 - 10(57.1)

   = 900 - 571

 Qd  = 329
```

Comment: Yes that's right, this is the usual approach to this kind of problems

Comment: if it is correct, how come when insert it into Qs i got different answer?              Qs = (57.1 -15)/0.05 = 842

Comment: Problem was due to a calculation error, look at my answer

Answer (score 1):

The equilibrium of price and quantity is at the point $(p^*,q^*)$ where the following equation is satisfied:
$$Q_d=q^*=Q_s$$

Thus we want to find the unique solution of this system of equations:
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
10p+Q_d=900 \\ 
p-0.05Q_s=15
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

Firstly we set $Q_d=q^*=Q_s$, which gives us:
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
10p+q^*=900 \\ 
p-0.05q^*=15
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
$$\Leftrightarrow
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
q^*=900-10p \\ 
p-0.05\cdot(900-10p)=15
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
$$\Leftrightarrow
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
q^*=900-10p \\ 
\frac32p=45+15=60
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
$$\Leftrightarrow
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
q^*=900-10p \\ 
p^*=p=40
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
$$\Leftrightarrow
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
q^*=900-10p^*=900-10\cdot 40=500 \\ 
p^*=40
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

Thus the equilibrium point is $(p^*,q^*)=(40,500)$.

---

Let's control if this is the right answer:

- $Q_d=900-10\cdot 40=500$
- $Q_s=\frac {p-15}{0.05}=\frac {40-15}{0.05}=\frac{25}{0.05}=500$